# Objective-c: string length with spaces included

Tags: iphone, xcode, string, spaces

I am trying to get the number of characters in a string including spaces.
If I have a string saying: "hello how are you?"
and I run this code:

```
 NSUInteger newLength = [myString length];
```

it returns 15.
There are 18 characters though when you include spaces... so what code should I use? Or am I going to have to run code to replace all of the spaces with some character like an asterix, count the number of characters and then set the string back to it's original string. That wouldn't be too bad except I have to do this numerous times so I'm looking for a quicker way. Thanks!

Comment: `[@"hello how are you?" length]` returns 18

Comment: See if you are missing any of *"how"*, *"are"* or *"you"* in your original string ;-)

Comment: length counts spaces in strings. Double check your code.

Comment: It wasn't working... I commented out all the code I had to replace things such as "on my way" with "omw" it started working. I put that code back in without the /* comment marks */ and it started working again! :o Must have been an Xcode glitch..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you post your string creation code? It seems strange to me. But NSString length doc does say:

> The number of Unicode characters in the receiver.

In any case, you could get the c string and use strlen, maybe that would help.

```
size_t length = strlen([myString cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html)..

```
[string length];
```

Returns the number of Unicode characters in the receiver. `Space`  is also a unicode character

Answer (score 0):

You use this to get the length of the string, including spaces:

```
NSUInteger newLength = [myString length];
```

(that is, you should not be returned 15, but 18)